# carouFredSel carousel jumps on mobile

Tags: carousel, caroufredsel

I'm use carouFredSel plugin for responsive carousel. 
When scroll bottom (on mobile), browser address bar pannel will hide, slider update height and jump to top. And when scroll to top, browser address bar pannel will show and slider update sizes and jump to top too. How fix it?

I call callback 'updateSizes' some times and carousel calculate mobile browser url bar height) only when scroll top, and only when scroll bottom after this bar hide

```
$('.container').carouFredSel({
  auto: false,
  circular: false,
  infinite: false,
  responsive: true,
  width: '100%',
  height: 'variable', 
  items: {
    visible: 1,
    start: 1,
    height: 'variable', 
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $("body").attr("height",$(document).scrollTop());
});


$(window).on("resize", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).scrollTop($("body").attr("height"))
});
```